# Drive won't boot from its Grub, but will from another drive's Grub, after cloning, why?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, cloning, uuid

It was a month ago, so if you ask me on details, I might still remember, but better act on information that can be given as of now. Due to the lack of time, I did not ask for help here.

---

I have cloned my SATA SSD drive to a bigger NVMe drive.

- The original SATA drive boots fine.
- The new NVMe drive will boot only via the SATA Grub loader where I must select the NVMe booting drive.

---

Some outputs of helpful commands follow:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1207A335-32CA-4B6C-A508-29A0E85597C4

Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048    194559    192512    94M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 194560 488396799 488202240 232,8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1207A335-32CA-4B6C-A508-29A0E85597C4

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    2048    194559    192512    94M EFI System
/dev/sda2  194560 488396799 488202240 232,8G Linux filesystem
```

---

I found a possibly useful script called [`bootinfoscript` on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), it contains way too much information, but that is the point, right(?)

```
# ./bootinfoscript

                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Linux Mint 19 Tara
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   488,397,167   488,397,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       194,559       192,512 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         194,560   488,396,799   488,202,240 Data partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/nvme0n1                                                       
/dev/nvme0n1p1   4966-E925                              vfat       
/dev/nvme0n1p2   f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa   ext4       
/dev/sda1        7C00-9D19                              vfat       
/dev/sda2        b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/fuse        /run/user/1000/doc       fuse       (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/nvme0n1p1   /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p2   /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=800x600
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0 ro  quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0' {
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon, with Linux 4.15.0-39-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-39-generic-advanced-b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-39-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0 ro  quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon, with Linux 4.15.0-39-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-39-generic-recovery-b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-39-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Tara (19) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa ro quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Linux Mint 19 Tara (19) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa' {
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic--f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa ro quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon, with Linux 4.15.0-39-generic (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic--f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa ro quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon, with Linux 4.15.0-39-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic-root=UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa ro recovery nomodeset-f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa ro recovery nomodeset
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
    }
}

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b235cea3-ea5b-4571-a252-b75b9cb3f5f0   /           ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7C00-9D19                              /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077          0       1

# the swap file was created during installation
#/swapfile                                   none        swap    sw                  0       0

# RAM disk
none                                        /ramdisk    tmpfs    size=2G,mode=0777  0       0

# auto-mount of windows drive
#/dev/disk/by-uuid/9CDAC383DAC357E2 /mnt/9CDAC383DAC357E2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro 0 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-Pd0sZIg3/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

---

I don't know what to do with it, I've tried too many things to even remember them.

I hope the above information would be helpful, otherwise, I am stuck.

---

The current behavior of the NVMe drive - if I try to boot directly from it, it automatically reboots.

I just do it like this for now:

[image: I just do it like this for now]

---

I do recall one more detail: I used GParted to change the partition UUIDs on the new drive and edited `fstab` accordingly.

---

I believe the problem arises from both drives having the same disk UUID, am I right?

If so, how shall I proceed now?

---

What I've tried:

```
# tune2fs /dev/nvme0n1 -U random

tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvme0n1
```

So, I suppose changing the whole disk UUID is done in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Disk UUIDs

I believe this was the main culprit and was in need of a change.

It was as simple as booting up the system on the SATA drive and running:

```
# gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
```

<kbd>x</kbd> for experts menu

<kbd>g</kbd> for new disk GUID

<kbd>R</kbd> for randomize

<kbd>w</kbd> to write changes to disk

<kbd>y</kbd> to confirm

The disk UUID had been changed... No need to change both of them, of course.

```
# fdisk -l | grep -i identifier

Disk identifier: 989573D5-37E7-437A-B680-9410F7234A94
Disk identifier: 1207A335-32CA-4B6C-A508-29A0E85597C4
```

---

### Partitions UUIDs

Again, to change those I used:

```
# gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
```

<kbd>x</kbd> for experts menu

<kbd>c</kbd> for new partition UUID

<kbd>1</kbd> for the first partition; repeat these steps for the second partition

<kbd>R</kbd> for randomize

<kbd>w</kbd> to write changes to disk

<kbd>y</kbd> to confirm

---

### GRUB update

This was as simple as running:

```
# update-grub
```

---

### Initrd regeneration

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

---

### UEFI BIOS settings

The boot options had to be removed and updated.

The NVMe drive boots just fine now.

---

### Notes

- I do not use `chroot` for cloning. I use plain `cat` or more convenient `pv` for disk cloning purposes. I read something about it now. I never needed it, ever. And I cloned like a hundred of drives already.
- Whenever I want to do an exact copy I do that on my SATA server, but this new M.2 PCIe is not exactly *pluggable* to it. So I elaborated a little. It is out of the scope of this Q & A.
- I heard there are adapters, but I am not a fan of those, so I used my server as a middleman over the local network.
- I do not like complications. Cloning systems, be it Linux or Windows is rather easy to me. But in a case like this (SATA to M.2) was a bit of a pain.
- That was because on one drive was Linux and on the second there was Windows. And I wanted to keep everything in place, no re-installation, no `rsync`, or whatever one might use to copy. I do *clone* exact duplicates instead.
- All you need is your brain and `gdisk` which I usually use to fix PMBR and such things, which are unavoidable with my methods but extremely quick to resolve.
- This case was different, though, I did prepare a lot. Like doing (1:1) backups and such. It was my personal computer and I wanted just to switch over the system drives: M.2 + Windows & SATA + Linux. I wanted to make it the other way around.
- This question arose once I needed to make sure the new Linux drive is doing fine as it is my primary operating system...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information it is hard to say what exactly is going on, your assumption with a UUID issue is most likely true.

Here is how I would proceede to get your challenge done:

- Clear the NVME using dd and /dev/zero. It should be sufficient to use bs=512 count=4
- Create new partitions and file systems on the NVME.
- Boot into a live system.
- Copy the data from the SSD partitions to the NVME partitions.
- Install Grub on the NVME, update /etc/fstab, update grub.cfg.

For the last point I recommend the following method:

- While still beeing on the live system, create a new "root"  directory, mount the NVME's root file system there.
- `mount --bind` `/dev, /proc, /sys` into the new "root". E.g. `mount --bind /dev /mnt/nvmeroot/dev`
- chroot into the new "root" using: `chroot /mnt/nvmeroot/ /bin/bash`
- Use `blkid` to find out new partition UUIDs, update /etc/fstab accordingly.
- Install grub onto the nvme e.g. using `grub-install`
- Update grubs config file with `update-grub or grub2-mkconfig`
- Exit the chroot.
- Unmount bind mounts, and the new "root".
- Reboot from the NVME.

In case something does not work:

- Use the the `e` (edit) button in grub, and remove linux boot arguments as `quiet, splash, rhgb` options so you can see error messages during boot.
- Reboot using the live system, mount the new "root", do the bind mounts, chroot and fix the issue, try again.

Comment: Why don't you try starting at: "In case something does not work"?

Comment: A UUID is a Unique Identifier ID, it is simply NOT supposed to be duplicated. As soon as duplicated it would loose its main purpose of beeing UNIQUE.

Comment: If you do not understand the last sentence, try reading the whole post.

Comment: You do not need to wipe out disks to deal with UUID issues.

Comment: True, but not everything that's possible is a good idea. And doing a proper update of the grub config is not hard, nor does it need a UUID duplication.

Comment: I am not sure if you are more interested on arguing or improving your answer. You missed the initrd (re)generation btw.

Answer (score 0):

> Drive won't boot... after cloning, why?

I do not have a `/etc/default/grub` handy but I will use a line from your bootinfo script

```
# auto-mount of windows drive
#/dev/disk/by-uuid/9CDAC383DAC357E2 /mnt/9CDAC383DAC357E2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro 0 0
```

so your original drive has UUID *whatever*

you clone the contents of that disk to a new disk, or NVME thing.  And the contents of grub on the new disk will still all reference uuid *whatever* which was the old disk, not the current new disk.

That new disk will not have the same UUID as the original, you have to correct everywhere it was used, basically `/etc/default/grub` and follow that with a `grub2-mkconfig` and also correct your `/etc/fstab`.

> I believe the problem arises from both drives having the same disk UUID, am I right?

UUID = universally unique identifier.  The UUID should be different.

There are a handful of ways to mount a disk... by-uuid or by-id or by-name or by-label or by-path of the top of my head.  I do not know if all linux distributions follow this model but if you look under `/dev/disk/` you will *should* see sub folders

- by-id
- by-label
- by-path
- by-uuid

if you do *by-name* then that is simply calling out the disk from `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sd??` which is not unique and i recommend against doing... if there is only ever one disk present then it would be `/dev/sda` and work but it would not be unique and would not be explicit so over time you take your chances.  And things may be further complicated with an NVME showing up differently as `/dev/nvme????`

**from your fdisk:**

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 1207A335-32CA-4B6C-A508-29A0E85597C4

Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048    194559    192512    94M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 194560 488396799 488202240 232,8G Linux filesystem
```

- look under `/dev/disk/?` and find that corresponding identifier.
- correct your boot files to use this new nvme disk explicitly to boot it.
- correct the `/etc/fstab` on that disk to use that identifier, it **will** have the text referencing the old disk because you cloned.

Comment: `I used GParted to change the partition UUIDs on the new drive and edited fstab accordingly.`  you change uuid with gparted after system is running, but you are NOT changing the UUID of the disk on the disk, it will revert back to it's unique id on next boot or power cycle

Comment: fstab is part 2 of the fix, part 1 is modifying grub correctly to reference the new disk or in you case nvme

Comment: changing a disk UUID is a horrible way to solve this problem